Find average of data from one column into another column but only if the data in a third column matches?
I'm working on an excel file for work, in which we are cataloguing the complexity of project pieces in Column H. I would like to include an "average" complexity for each individual project into Column I. My problem is that I don't want every single project averaged together, but rather, only ones that have matching numbers in column A.
So, basically:
If Column A has project number 17332 in three rows, which are categorized as 2, 4, and 2 in column H, I want the average of Column H within those three matching Column A's to appear in I.
If Column A then has project number 13229 in a different set of rows, it would also populate Column I with their individual average of H.
In the end it would be:



Column A
Column H
Column I




17332
2
2.67


17332
4
2.67


17332
2
2.67


13229
1
1.75


13229
1
1.75


13229
3
1.75


13229
2
1.75



(and so on)
(Not sure if my table is working. doesn't seem to like me.)
I'm assuming this has something to do with the AVERAGEIF command, but I know just enough of VBA or conditional formatting to get myself in trouble, and I would rather not break the company's storage sheet if I can get away with it.

AVERAGEIF will do what you want.

In column I you can use:
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,@A:A,H:H)


Works perfectly, originally asked if there was any way to remove the #DIV/0! error when column H is empty, but found the answer for myself. Posting the solution to that here, in case anyone else needs help with it:
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(A:A,@A:A,H:H),"")
